# How to detect shake event

Tags: java, android, detect, shake

I have extensively searched the internet to find my answer but no luck. I was wondering if it was possible to shake the android device and have the phone recognize it. After the phone recognized it, it would start a new intent(like a picture). Please help, any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Shake as in movement ? see this post [detect movement][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157521/how-to-detect-the-movement-of-the-device

Comment: In a way it is a duplicate, I saw that forum thread buy I couldn't understand the answer to it.

Comment: look at the tutorial in my answer.